# How to receive object in java socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm new in java network programming.

I wrote a simple client-server code that sends object of a class from client to server.

I used `PrintStream` to send object and it's ok, but cannot receive it at the server when using `BufferedReader`

Client Code:

```
public class Client3 {

public String username;
public String password;

public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
{
    Client3 account = new Client3();
    account.username = "PJA";
    account.password = "123456";

    Socket s = new Socket("localhost",6000);
    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    pr.println(account);
}

}
```

Server Code:

```
public class Server3 {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(6000);
    Socket s = s1.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    Client3 a = new Client3();
    a = in.readLine(); // give a compilation error.

}

}
```

`readline()` throws a compilation error because it takes only a string.

so my question is: "Is there a way to receive object of a class?"

Comment: @Abdelhak I want to receive object that i sent in client.

Comment: But i know this is compilation error because it takes only a string but iam looking for a way to receive that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: "Is there a way to receive object of a class?"

A: Yes, there are many MANY ways:

1. Java [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html)
2. Java [SOAP Web services](https://dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)
3. You can use native Java serialization and write directly to a Java socket (basically, re-invent your own RMI): http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-of-java-objects-through-sockets/, or http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=10472.  If you mark your objects "serializable", then you can simply use`outputStream.writeObject()` to write and `ObjectInputStream()` to read.
4. You read and write your object state into JSON and send JSON text over your socket: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/
5. Etc. etc.

Option 3) is closest to what you're asking about. I'd also encourage you to consider Option 4).  Here's a good tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: Thanks i tried native java serialization and worked good for me . +1